# What does the equation $f(A)=A$ tell about the function $f$?

Tags: functions

Given a function $f: A \to A$ what does $f(A)=A$ mean? Does it mean $f$ is bijective on $A$? I could see it being bijective on $A$ if $A$ is a finite set, but I'm not sure what happens if $A$ is infinite? $f(A)=A$ surely means $f$ is surjective whether or not $A$ is finite. But I don't know how to go about proving the injectivity of $f$?

Comment: $f(A)=A$ iff $f$ is surjective. No relation with injectivity.

Comment: It means $f$ is bijective only if $A$ is a finite set.

Comment: @Bernard Even if $A$ is an infinite set, $f$ **might** still be bijective.  Consider for example $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}~:~ f(n) = n$. Here, $f(\mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{N}$ and $f$ is a bijection even though $\mathbb{N}$ is not a finite set.

Comment: @user2661923: I know. I meant ‘it means  for sure $f$ is bijective …’

Comment: @Bernard I figured, but I also suspected that the OP would not know that.

Comment: You're right, one should carefully check whether the phrasing has any ambiguity. I do not always…

Comment: @user2661923 Ah yes, I see your point but Bernard is correct. Like him, in my head, I usually translate a sentence into either "there exists" or "for all" and since I was talking about any such function in general because I didn't give much information about $f$, I was talking in the sense of "for all" but I should phrase things better.

Comment: @Bernard In case where $A$ is finite, how do I prove $f$ is injective? Proving surjective is not a problem because the range $f(A)$ is equal to the codomain $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is finite, then $f$ is surjective $\iff f$ is injective.  To see this, experiment with $A = \{1,2,\cdots, 10\}$, trying to create $f$ that is injective but not surjective, and trying to create $g$ that is surjective but not injective.  What it comes down to is **exactly** how many elements are in the range of $f$ versus the number of elements in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Re last two comments, I am assuming that "A is finite" means that the number of elements in $A$ is a finite number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion $f(A)=A$ does *not* tell you that $f$ is injective. For instance, if $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$, then $f([-1,1])=[-1,1]$, but $f$ is not injective on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: How did you come up with a counter example so quickly? What was your thought process?

Comment: I though about the sine function. You have $\sin([-2\pi,2\pi])=[-1,1]$ and $f$ is not injective on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then I replaced $\sin(x)$ with $\sin(2\pi x)$, so that I would have a non-injective function that maps $[-1,1]$ onto itself.